# Symfony 3 Doctrine MySQL - generate entities with @ORM annotations

Tags: orm, console, doctrine, symfony, entities

according to Symfony 3 docs after running 3 commands:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeBlogBundle xml
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeBlogBundle
```

I should get the result of something like:

```
// src/Acme/BlogBundle/Entity/BlogComment.php
namespace Acme\BlogBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\BlogComment
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="blog_comment")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class BlogComment
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $author
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="author", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $author;
    .....
```

unfortunately instead of I get roughly mapped class with getters and setters looking like so:

```
<?php
namespace Clashers\PanelBundle\Entity;

/**
 * Users
 */
class Users
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }
```

Does any of you have faced such an issue and have solved it with no need to manually assign every property to DB type, column?
Is there any Doctrine setting(s) I've missed to generate those entities properly?

Comment: Is it possible that you may have run these out of sequence or something?  Consider deleting the generated xml mapping files as well as the entity files and trying again.

Comment: Have you checked your database Users table? It should mirror your table structure. If you table isn't setup correctly that could be why.

Comment: And you definitely will need to delete the generated xml mapping files.

Comment: @Cerad I've run command 2 time with same effect. Deleted xml and entities before 2nd run.

Comment: @Sarcoma I'm using MySQL DB what do you mean by "setup correctly"?

Comment: Just that the code you provided looks fine, I mean double check the database is as you expect. Have you deleted out the generated xml files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, problem solved. I've just rerun once again those command and somehow I've just missed an error that was caused by having already created Users entity. This will likely prevent Doctrine from creating other entities and running last command

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeBlogBundle
```

without fully processed

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src
```

will end up with missing annotations like I've had.